# Extend Inline FAL element - TYPO3

Tags: typo3, flux

I need to add extra filed to add some properties to the fal media element for example **email id and phone number**.How can I implement this as an  **IRRE** field.Is it possible?

```
<f:section name="Configuration">
    <flux:form id="teamAndNetwork"  options="{group: 'FCE', Fluidcontent: {sorting: 150}}" label="Team And Network">
        <flux:field.inline.fal name="settings.images" multiple="TRUE" maxItems="20" />
    </flux:form>
    </f:section>
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and provide a little bit more information on what you want to archive. It is unclear for me what you are asking.

Comment: @pgampe i edited my question.Is it clear for you now?

Comment: So you need to extend the default FAL element with as many text elements as you want.. like a field for name,address etc ??